# Testing RxWorker for WorkManager

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-workmanager

I want to try out work manager for the first time. I am used to rxJava so I decided to implement my work manager using RxWorker. But the testing aspect is giving me headache.Basically, the work manager checks firebase to get latest changes to latest changes to particular document (This is not the best use case I know).But the problem is in the test returns without waiting for success or failure.It returns when the work manager is still running.

This is my work manager implementation

```
class MidiSyncWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : RxWorker(context, params) {
    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        return Injection.provideSharePrefsRepo.midiArchiveVersion()
                .flatMapObservable { currentVersion ->
                    Injection.provideOnlineRepo.latestMidiArchive()
                            .filter { onlineMidi -> onlineMidi.version > currentVersion }
                }.firstOrError()
                .map { onlineMidi ->
                    val outputData = Data.Builder()
                            .putString(KEY_FIREBASE_ARCHIVE_PATH, onlineMidi.url)
                    Result.success(outputData.build()) }
                 }
                 .onErrorReturn { Result.failure() }

}
```

This is my test

```
   fun midiSyncVersionCheck_success_onlineVersionDiffersFromLocalVersion() {
       // create request
       val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MidiSyncWorker>()
               .build()

       wmRule.workManager.enqueue(request).result.get()

       val workInfo = wmRule.workManager.getWorkInfoById(request.id).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

       assertThat(workInfo.state, `is`(WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED))
   }
```

I expected the test to wait until workmanager returns success or failure. But it returns while work manager is still running

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: is <SUCCEEDED>
but: was <RUNNING>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WorkManager makes available a couple of ways to test your `Worker` classes. You can find all the details on [WorkManager Testing documentation page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing).

The original [`WorkManagerTestInitHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/WorkManagerTestInitHelper) only supports `Worker` classes, meanwhile, the newly introduce in (WorkManager v2.1.0-alpha01) [`TestListenableWorkerBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/TestListenableWorkerBuilder) can be used to test both `ListenableWorker` classes and the other classes that derives from it (like `CoroutineWorker` and `RxWorker`.

In your particular case, you should be able to do:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker.Result
import androidx.work.testing.TestListenableWorkerBuilder
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.`is`
import org.junit.Assert.assertThat
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4

@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class MyWorkTest {
    private lateinit var context: Context

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    }

    @Test
    fun testMidiSyncWorker() {
        // Get the ListenableWorker
        val worker = TestListenableWorkerBuilder<MidiSyncWorker>(context).build()

        // Start the work synchronously
        val result = worker.startWork().get()

        assertThat(result, `is`(Result.success()))
    }
}
```

In this way you're calling synchrously your worker class.

In this case you need to use the as a test dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
def work_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"
```

You can find a similar, complete, sample (for a `CoroutineWorker`), on the [Kotlin's coroutine Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/).

Comment: Thanks for the response! But how to deal with the following error that occurs when I run adapted sample you've provided?:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create an instance of ListenableWorker`

Comment: Which Worker class are you using?  Take a look at the documentation and see if you can find which kind of test work for you: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing

Comment: @c0nst. you probably have fixed this by now but I ran into the same IllegalStateException Today. The reason was I use a seperate dagger component for testing and forgot to add the worker module to the test component.

Comment: Awesome! Needed this for CoroutineWorker, thanks.